# Передача массива между страницами

Tags: php, массивы, post, form

Здравствуйте, есть массив чекбоксов $_POST['ch'], переданный на страницу через

```html
<form method="POST">
```

как мне передать массив и на другую страницу?

со страницы iphone.php на страницу order.php передается массив с числовыми данными через ФОРМ с методом ПОСТ ($_POST['ch']), потом со страницы order.php формируется и передается другой массив так же через ФОРМ с методом ПОСТ ($_POST['osel']), так же с числовыми данными на страницу succ.php. Как мне вместе с $_POST['osel'] передать и $_POST['ch'] на страницу succ.php?

Comment: как минимум, с помощью сессий.

Comment: без сессий реально?

Comment: вы бы сперва задачу уточнили, отредактировав свой вопрос, и тогда можно было бы сказать конкретнее, что лучше для этого использовать.

Comment: со страницы iphone.php на страницу order.php передается массив с числовыми данными через ФОРМ с методом ПОСТ ($_POST['ch']), потом со страницы order.php формируется и передается другой массив так же через ФОРМ с методом ПОСТ ($_POST['osel']), так же с числовыми данными на страницу succ.php. Как мне вместе с $_POST['osel'] передать и $_POST['ch'] на страницу succ.php?

Comment: $_POST['ch'] сохраняете в сессию, и потом добавляете к передаваемому $_POST['osel'] значение из сессии, а после этого очищаете сессию.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самым оптимальным вариантом решением задачи стало создание сессии.

Answer (score 0):

Можно поместить данные в скрытые input'ы, только не стоит забывать, что если эти данные запрещено изменять, то доверять данным, полученным из формы нельзя.

```
<form method="POST" action="/some-other-page">
  <input type=text name=osel>
  <input type=hidden name=ch value=1>
  <input type=hidden name=ch value=2>
  <input type=hidden name=ch value=3>
  <input type=submit value=Send>
</form>
```

[image: скриншот отправленных данных]

Comment: Мне надо что-бы с той страницы, куда был отправлен массив можно было его отправить на следующую страницу.

Comment: Ну надо, так делай. Откуда там вообще ещё одна страница взялась? Вопрос хоть понятно сформулируй.

Comment: Ну так я же и интересуюсь как сделать!

Comment: Ну так опиши в вопросе по шагам, что должно происходить. Есть форма, она отправляется на какой-то адрес - на один адрес. Откуда вдруг берётся ещё одна страница??

Comment: Сейчас отпишу подробнее в вопросе.

Comment: Я обновил ответ.